# routeWarning causing infinite loop

Tags: react-router

I am getting the following error in Chrome browser in 'development' mode while upgrading our app to 2.0.0-rc4 from Router:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

[image]

This looks to be coming from an infinite loop in `warning.js`.

This can be reproduced in my application with the following:

```
import routerWarning from 'react-router/lib/warning'
routerWarning(true, 'a test message')
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have either `lib` or `.` in `resolve.modulesDirectories` in your webpack config. Don't do that – it causes problems broadly with third-party libraries.

Comment: My modulesDirectories is: `modulesDirectories: ["", "shared", "node_modules"]`

Comment: I think you are correct that it is a problem with loading. When i run `require('warning')` in my source code, I can see that it is loading from the warning package, but inside of react-router's `warning.js`, that same `require('warning')` is loading itself (causing the infinite loop). Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to fix this.

Comment: You need to drop `""` from `modulesDirectories` – it's broadly unsafe and will break randomly when this sort of thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like react-router is requiring the `warning` package in a file named `warning.js`. This is causing an infinite loop in my configuration as react-router's`warning.js` is requiring itself instead of requiring the package.

I was able to work around the issue by including `"warning": "2.1.0"` in my package.json and changing my `resolve.modulesDirectories` to include the `warning` package directory before any others:

```
modulesDirectories: [
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'node_modules', 'warning'),
  "", "shared", "node_modules"
]
```